# How do I use publishResults() method when extending Filters in Android?

Tags: android, filter, autocompletetextview

I'm working on an autocompletetextview that will work off of a key value system, and am trying to find out what I need to do to make publishResults work, as the results param being passed to publishResults here is correct in the debugger, however I have no idea what it should correspond to or how to cause it to display the results, can anyone help? the creation of this object is in another file, and looks like this:

```
autoCompleteBox.setAdapter(new AutoCmpAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line));
```

and the rest of the code is as follows:

```
public class AutoCmpAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    protected Filter filter;
    protected ArrayList<String> items;
    protected ArrayList<String> res;
    String lWds[] = { "HOMER", "TOM" };
    String sWds[] = { "SIMPSON", "JONES" };

    public AutoCmpAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        filter = new PhysFilter();
        res = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    private class PhysFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults f = new FilterResults();
            res.clear();
            if (constraint != null) {
                ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int x = 0; x < sWds.length; x++) {
                    if (sWds[x].toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        res.add(lWds[x]);
                    }
                }
                f.values = res.toArray();
                f.count = res.size();
            }
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count > 0) {
                Log.println(Log.INFO, "Results", "FOUND");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                Log.println(Log.INFO, "Results", "-");
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all don't use String array.

to work for key value pair you can adjust your If statement..
try this in your onCreate

```
AutoCompleteTextView mAutoCompleteTextView;
ArrayList<String> lWds = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mAutoCompleteTextView=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.testAutoComplete);


    final AutoCmpAdapter adapter= new AutoCmpAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,lWds);
    mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);

        }
    });
}
```

and adapter class like

```
  public class AutoCmpAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    protected Filter filter;
    protected ArrayList<String> items;
    protected ArrayList<String> res;

    String sWds[] = { "SIMPSON", "JONES" };

    public AutoCmpAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<String> listData) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId,0,listData);

        filter = new PhysFilter();
        res = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    private class PhysFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults f = new FilterResults();
            res.clear();
            if (constraint != null) {
                ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int x = 0; x < sWds.length; x++) {
                    if (sWds[x].toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        res.add(sWds[x]);
                    }
                }
                f.values = res;//.toArray();
                f.count = res.size();
            }
            return f;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count > 0) {
                Log.println(Log.INFO, "Results", "FOUND");
                lWds.clear();
                lWds.addAll((ArrayList<String>) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                Log.println(Log.INFO, "Results", "-");
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where does lWds come from in publishResults??

Comment: @artworkadシ from the right index finger thinking it's the left index finger??  Haha..it's from the OP's code

Comment: When ``constraint`` is null, you probably want to return **all values**, rather than **none** - because no constraint usually means "no search" not "search for nothing".  This will also simply your publishResults() code.     e.g could change your performFiltering() to: ``if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    results.count = listData.size();
                    results.values = listData;} else {/*do search*/}

Comment: Good example of how to use performFiltering and publishResults. Used it to solve my filtering issue. Perhaps good to share that the filtered list needs to be immutable. Otherwise, every time a user does a backspace, the list to be filtered becomes fixed to the "filtered" list, which is not what we want of course. Thanks!